# bash script to login to multiple Linux servers and collect the output of multiple commands through ssh

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I need to login and collect output of below commands from multiple GNU/Linux servers through `SSH`. I have done password-less `SSH` authentication. I wanted to do this with bash script.

```
df -lh | awk '{if ($5 >= 20) { print $6 "  " $2 "   "  $3  "  " $5 }}'
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print 100 - $5}'
```

---

I tried the command below, but instead of a quoted "command", if giving single command like `df`  it's working .. but giving like long commands:

```
df -lh | awk '{if ($5 >= 20) { print $6 "  " $2 "   "  $3  "  " $5 }}'
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print 100 - $5}'
```

it's not working..

Comment: What's the difference between the two snippets?

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? What commands did you actually run (what you show doesn't involve SSH)?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using some parallel SSH tool such as '[clush](https://github.com/cea-hpc/clustershell)' or '[pdsh](https://code.google.com/p/pdsh/)' ,the output will be much more elegant.

Say our server names are 'host01' till 'host09', your command would look like this:

```
clush -Bw host0[1-9] "df -lh | awk '{if (\$5 >= 20) { print \$6 \""  \"" \$2 "\"   \""  \$3  "\"  \"" \$5 }}';top -b -n1 | grep 'Cpu(s)' | awk '{print 100 - \$5}'"
```

Pay attention to the escaping.

Answer (score 0):

step 1: write it to a script

```
cat script.sh
df -lh | awk '{if ($5 >= 20) { print $6 "  " $2 "   "  $3  "  " $5 }}'
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print 100 - $5}'
```

step 2: `scp` it to hosts. (scp is secure copy), host is in `$h`

```
scp script.sh $h:/tmp
```

step 3: execute it

```
ssh $h bash /tmp/script.sh
```

You may wish to redirect output

```
ssh $h bash /tmp/script.sh > result-$h.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run those lines without writing a separated script file, you will need to enclose the commands with double quotes and escape any character that might conflict with that. For example:

```
ssh your-host "
df -lh | awk '{if (\$5 >= 20) { print \$6 \"  \" \$2 \"   \"  \$3  \"  \" \$5 }}'
top -b -n1 | grep \"Cpu(s)\" | awk '{print 100 - \$5}'"
```

Or using single quotes:

```
ssh your-host'
df -lh | awk '"'"'{if ($5 >= 20) { print $6 "  " $2 "   "  $3  "  " $5 }}'"'"'
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '"'"'{print 100 - $5}'"'"
```

Or using here-document:

```
ssh your-host "$(cat << 'END'
df -lh | awk '{if ($5 >= 20) { print $6 "  " $2 "   "  $3  "  " $5 }}'
top -b -n1 | grep "Cpu(s)" | awk '{print 100 - $5}'
END
)"
```

This last option has the drawback of using more lines, but it doesn't require that you change anything on your commands.